# How do you change the axis on a heatmap using python?

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to plot a heatmap with different values of A. The axis is showing the number of iterations which is 0 to 30 instead of the value of A which should be between 0 and 5.

```
import numpy as np
from math import e
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from ipywidgets import interactive   
%matplotlib inline


def ricker(A, x):
    return x * e**(A * (1 - x))


import seaborn as sns

A1 = np.linspace(0,5,30)
A2 = np.linspace(0,5,30)

def F(A1,A2):

     A1,A2 = np.meshgrid(A1,A2)
     Lyap = 0
     x = 0.5
     for i in range(0,5000):
          if i % 2==0:
              A = A2
          else:
              A = A1

          Lyap = Lyap + np.log(abs((1-A*x)*e**(A - A*x)))
          x = ricker(A, x)
      Lyap = Lyap/5000
      return Lyap
 z = F(A1,A2)
 plt.figure(figsize=(16, 16))
 ax = sns.heatmap(z)
 ax.invert_yaxis()
```

Comment: I'm getting an error with your code: `NameError: name 'e' is not defined`

Comment: Sorry I included the imports that should fix that error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify the x/y tick labels, e.g.

```
ax = sns.heatmap(z, xticklabels=A1, yticklabels=A2)
```

The result is pretty ugly

[image: rawticklabels]

You can do better if you format a bit

```
xlabels = ['{:3.1f}'.format(x) for x in A1]
ylabels = ['{:3.1f}'.format(y) for y in A2]
ax = sns.heatmap(z, xticklabels=xlabels, yticklabels=ylabels)
```

[image: betterstrings]

but you can also use fewer tick labels

```
ax = sns.heatmap(z, xticklabels=A1, yticklabels=A2)
ax.set_xticks(ax.get_xticks()[::3])
ax.set_xticklabels(xlabels[::3])
ax.set_yticks(ax.get_yticks()[::3])
ax.set_yticklabels(ylabels[::3])
```

[image: somelabels]